# Microsoft OneNote 2016 won't connect to OneDrive

Tags: sync, onedrive, office365, microsoft-onenote

I am having an issue with Microsoft OneNote (Office 365 ProPlus) 2016 where it has issues connecting, creating and syncing with OneDrive. Effectively anything where OneNote has to work with the cloud has an issue. The other office apps seem to work correctly.

This is an error I get creating a notebook:

[image]

This is an error I get trying to see the notebooks on 'my account':

[image]

This is an error I get trying to open an existing notework with I created without issue on OneNote online:

[image]

Generally any part of the program which talks to the web breaks. I have also had numerous issues where sign-on was unreliable and required restarting the program etc.

It works fine if I save the file in the directory structure of my OneNote folder on the PC itself.

I have tried :

- Wiping the installation of Office and installing 2013.
- Disabling all firewalls
- Resetting Internet Explorer as detailed [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_windows8/sorry-we-are-having-some-temporary-server-issues/f66d6f91-1a15-40dd-a012-49b3b3b17535)
- Deleting Office server related items from the registry as detailed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/es-ES/a78439b5-f854-434f-8caf-cab87285907b/sorry-we-are-having-some-temporary-server-issues)
- Obviously restarting etc

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: If you map OneDrive as a network drive on your computer and try saving it there does it work?

Comment: Yup that works but my understanding of how the sync in onenote works is that it would make it harder to share?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Honestly, I would just keep OneDrive mapped as a network share, and then open it from there. You won't have to signin to anything in OneNote itself. You should be able to share right from onedrive.com

Comment: Try [these tips](http://www.windowscentral.com/9-tips-help-you-fix-onedrive-sync-problems-windows-10) and report on results.

Comment: @harrymc OneDrive is fine, it's OneNote that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough info to be helpful here, you could see MS's OneNote diagnostic tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53336) to gather more, though I don't know if it's shareable.

There are also some somewhat generic options available from MS [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-issues-when-you-can-t-sync-OneNote-299495ef-66d1-448f-90c1-b785a6968d45); the only one that rings to me is the file>info>sync status, and the associated tests, which test your server. They have a team dedicated to this and I'd file a report there.

This is quite odd - particularly that the other office apps are working fine. I would try replicating on another machine with your account. This will help rule out issues external to the system. Then, I'd try it on another wifi, just to see - sometimes my dropbox fails as a canary-in-the-coalmine (a minute or two before my wiki kicks out or stutters).

Other than that, it sounds like you've got some sort of corruption issue - have you tried addressing each of the errors as they stand  (are you using odd characters, are you sure your permissions are set for this account correctly, etc.).

I'm not on a system that uses onenote right now, but I see doc/Damien's Notebook - shouldn't this end in *.onetoc?

Do you have multiple concurrent installs of office going by accident? Did you install over another?

Comment: did you figure this out?